# How to test code that calls top level functions in Kotlin?

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, kotlin, powermock

I am very new to Kotlin.

I have a class that calls a top level function (which makes a http call). I am trying to write unit tests for my class without having it go out to the network.

Is there a way to mock/powermock/intercept the call from my class to the Kotlin top level function?

```
class MyClass {
    fun someMethod() {
        // do some stuff
        "http://somedomain.com/some-rest/action".httpGet(asList("someKey" to "someValue")).responseString { (request, response, result) ->
            // some processing code
        }
    }
}
```

It is using the [kittinunf/Fuel library](https://github.com/kittinunf/Fuel) for the httpGet call.

It adds a top level function to String that ultimately calls a companion object function in Fuel (Fuel.get()).

The unit test needs to intercept the call to httpGet so that I can return a json string for the test.

Comment: Hey Boon.. Do u have complete example to do this? I'm trying to write Junit tests for my Kotlin fuel calls

Comment: I followed @miensol's suggestion and used Fuel.testMode() and the executeRequest override.

Comment: it will be of great help if u can post the code snippet or send a github link ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I encourage you to encapsulate remote API calls behind an interface that would be injected through constructor to the class using it:

```
class ResponseDto
interface SomeRest {
    fun action(data:Map<String,Any?>): ((ResponseDto)->Unit)->Unit
}
class FuelTests(val someRest: SomeRest) {
    fun callHttp(){
        someRest.action(mapOf("question" to "answer")).invoke { it:ResponseDto ->
            // do something with response 
        }
    }
}
```

Another way is to to inject a fake `Client` to be used by `Fuel`:

```
FuelManager.instance.client = object: Client {
    override fun executeRequest(request: Request): Response {
        return Response().apply {
            url = request.url
            httpStatusCode = 201
        }
    }
}

Fuel.testMode()

"http://somedomain.com/some-rest/action".httpGet(listOf()).responseString { request, response, result ->
    print(response.httpStatusCode) // prints 201
}
```

Comment: How could I do the same fake client injection with Java? I think the Fuel documentation is not clear enough for this cases.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that "top level functions" can be seen as static methods in disguise.

And from that point of view, the better answer is: do not use them in such a way. This leads to high, direct coupling; and makes your code harder to test. You definitely want to create some interface *Service* which all your objects should be using; and then use use dependency injection to equip your client code with some object that implements the *Service* interface.

By doing so, you also get rid of the requirement to Powermock completely.